# HTTPS Post Request with ESP8266

Tags: post, https, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to send an HTTPS POST request with a ESP8266. I can make the request just fine with python and cURL just when I try it with the ESP it doesn't work. A segment of my code is below

```
const char *host = "api.pushbullet.com";
const int httpsPort = 443;
const char fingerprint[] PROGMEM = "4C 70 C5 AE F3 30 E8 29 D1 9C 18 C6 2F 08 D0 6A A9 AA 19 0F";

Link = "/post";

httpsClient.print(String("POST ") + Link + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "/v2/pushes" + "\r\n" +
               "Access-Token: *************"+ "\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: application/json"+ "\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: 20"+ "\r\n" +
               "body: Hello World" + "\r\n\r\n");

Serial.println("request sent");
```

The request I'm trying to make is below. This works just fine in python

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Access-Token': '***********',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
data = '{"body":"Hello World","title":"Hi","type":"note"}'
response = requests.post('https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes', headers=headers, data=data)
```

And in cURL:

```
curl --header 'Access-Token: **********' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"body":"Hello World","title":"Hi","type":"note"}' --request POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
```

When I make the request with the Arduino code it returns "Error 411 (Length Required)!!".

This is probably due to some stupid mistake I've made but if anyone could help me fix my Arduino code I'd be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. your [http POST format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) are incorrect in a)host name, b)uri, and c)header/body separation;
2. your http body is not a valid json object.

Here is an example on sending the http (without using String):

```
const char *host = "api.pushbullet.com";
const char *uri = "/post/v2/pushes/";
const char *body ="{\"body\": \"Hello World\"}";  // a valid jsonObject

char postStr[40];
sprintf(postStr, "POST %s HTTP/1.1", uri);  // put together the string for HTTP POST

httpsClient.println(postStr);
httpsClient.print("Host: "); httpsClient.println(host);
httpsClient.println("Access-Token: *************");
httpsClient.println("Content-Type: application/json");
httpsClient.print("Content-Length: "); httpsClient.println(strlen(body));
httpsClient.println();    // extra `\r\n` to separate the http header and http body
httpsClient.println(body);
```

Comment: Can we please have the complete code? What's the `httpsClient` for example?

Comment: @jezmck, if you don't know what is the `httpsClient` or how to create an `httpsClient` instance, please read the examples that come with your ESP8266 Arduino IDE installation, specifically [this example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequest/HTTPSRequest.ino).

Answer (score 1):

General advice: when you use `cURL` always use `--verbose` to see the full HTTP exchange.

In your case it should be

```
httpsClient.print(String("POST ") + "/v2/pushes" + Link + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Access-Token: *************"+ "\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: application/json"+ "\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: 20"+ "\r\n" +
               "body: Hello World" + "\r\n\r\n");
```

Note how

- the path is "/v2/pushes/" plus identifier ("Link" in your case?)
- `Host` is just "api.pushbullet.com"

Side notes:

- make sure you send correct values for `Content-Length`
- [consider using `HTTPClient`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino) if you are not confident with low-level HTTP programming